# Coloring by 2D location in 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, location, scatter-plot, pca

I have a 3D scatter plot of first three principal components plotted by matplotlib.pyplot. For each point plotted, I also have a separate 2x1 numpy array which depicts its location in a 2D environment.
Is it possible to use the 2x1 arrays to introduce colouring by location in my 3D scatter plot?

This is an approximation of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotThreeComponents():

    lv_1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,7])
    lv_2 = np.array([3,2,1,0,7])
    lv_3 = np.array([0,1,0,5,7])

    location = np.array([[5,7,0,4,7],
                         [1,1,2,4,7]])

    plt.figure()

    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.scatter3D(lv_1, lv_2, lv_3, c=location, s = 4)

    ax.set_xlabel('PC1')
    ax.set_ylabel('PC2')
    ax.set_zlabel('PC3')

    plt.show()

    pass

plotThreeComponents()
```

I also tried to add this to the function:

```
colorList = []
for i in range(location.shape[1]):
    colorList.append(location[:,i])
```

To generate a list where each element is an array of shape (2, )
and then changed

```
ax.scatter3D(lv_1, lv_2, lv_3, c=colorList, s = 4)
```

However, I am still getting an Error message stating that "'c' argument has 10 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 5.", even if len(colorList) = 5

Column vectors of 'location' array depict coordinates in 2D space.
Location and lv_1, lv_2, lv_3 are linked indirectly.

what should be 'c' in 'ax.scatter3D' so that I get coloring by 2D location?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You can provide the [color as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426271/8881141).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. When I write this line:
"ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=location,  cmap = cm.coolwarm)"
where 'location' variable is 2xN array I get a ValueError stating that 'c' argument has 2*N elements which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size N.
I don't even understand the documentation which states: "[...]use a 2D array with a single row." My 'location' variable is a matrix where each vector corresponds to a location?
'location.T' also doesn't work.

Comment: You have to map the color values from 2D onto your 3D points. I understand that you provide x, y, and z as three 1D arrays of length N, so location must also be an array of length N containing the color values for each x-y-z in the three other arrays (think: lists). It is unclear though what location actually contains - x-y pairs? a list of color values for each x-y pair? You haven't been clear about this. I suggest providing [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I updated the question.
I turned my 2xN array into a list of len N where each element contains an array of shape (2, ) which depicts 2D location. However, I am still getting the same error message.
My location variable and x,y,z on scatter plot are not directly linked, however I would still like colourize data points in my scatter plot based on the vectors from my location variable.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't know what the numbers in `location` mean for the scatterplot (and neither do I). It expects an array like `[A, B, A, A, C]` telling it that points 1,3,4 are one category etc. What does a pair x-y in `location` mean in relation to your x-y-z data? You don't have a point [5, 1] in your scatter plot, and even if you had - will [5, 1] and [7, 1] belong to the same category? If not, what defines their categories?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure what you mean by category now. What I do in my code is this. I give a certain _function_ my column (2x1) vectors from `location` and the _function_ (eventually) provides me with 1D arrays `lv_1, lv_2, lv_3`. So `location[:, i]` corresponds to `lv_1[i], lv_2[i], lv_3[i]`, think of each `i` as a time step.  So when I plot the scatter plot, I want the point mapped by `lv_1[i], lv_2[i], lv_3[i]` to have a colour which is defined by 2D array `location[:, i]`. This is the relationship between x-y in `location` and x-y-z in scatter plot.

Comment: We haven't progressed here. That 2D location `[i]` refers to 3D point `[i]` is understood but what is the color of a 2D location like `[5,1]`? You still haven't defined this mapping.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I need to map column vectors from `location` to some colours or colour spectrum. pyplot.scatter documentation states that `c` can be "A 2D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA." So now I need to find a way of converting my `location` array into RGB or RGBA array, right? I hope I understand now.

Comment: Yup. That definition is the missing link. Maybe for `x<y` points in `location` are blue, otherwise red. Maybe for `x**2+y**2<20` points are yellow, otherwise green. Maybe `x+y` should fill the color spectrum blue to red. Matplotlib doesn't know, you haven't told it (and us) what this definition is. But we are now on the right track! So, I suggest you include this mapping definition (not necessarily as code) to the question.

Comment: Thank @Mr.T you for your help, I am now trying to create the RGBA arrays but I am encountering some new problems. I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71176465/14687313) . Thank you if you have any suggestions.