# How to map np.arrays to RGBA vectors using matplotlib.colors.Colormap ('Abstract class only' error)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, rgba, color-mapping

I am trying to convert 2xN *numpy array* into two colormaps. That is, I want to turn each row of the array to separate arrays of RGBA values. I am using the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as clrs


location = np.array([[0.72, 1.69, 4.85, 1.20, 0.45, 2.13, 3.65 , 4.03, 3.27, 4.59],
                     [4.02, 3.73, 2.95, 0.22, 1.81, 0.45, 3.30, 4.54, 2.74, 1.14]])

normalizeX = clrs.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = 5)
normalizeY = clrs.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = 5)

normX = normalizeX(location[0,:])
normY = normalizeY(location[1,:])

mapX = clrs.Colormap('Blues')
mapY = clrs.Colormap('Greens')

colorValues_X = mapX(normX)
colorValues_Y = mapY(normY)
```

I would expect the `colorValues_X` and `colorValues_Y` variables to hold the RGBA arrays but I am getting an **error statement** which I do not understand.
The error is `NotImplementedError: Abstract class only`.

As far as I know, the instance of the `Colormap` class only requires normalized array of numbers as its input to return the RGBA array.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: `mapX = clrs.get_cmsp('Blues')`. Note that `clrs.Colormap` is an abstract  class only.

Comment: There is a typo (`.get_cmap()`) in Johan's otherwise correct comment. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html) for a tutorial on how to create and alter colormaps.